# Why is the size of this struct 12 and not 10?

Tags: c++, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

I'm trying to parse ID3v2 tags, at least get important data like artist, title, and album, but I'm having trouble setting up the necessary structures.

```
struct ID3v2_frame{
  char id[4];
  unsigned int size;
  bool flags[2];
};
ID3v2_frame frame;
cout<<sizeof(frame)<<endl;
```

It's a problem with how I'm setting up a 4 byte int I think.
When I output sizeof(frame) it outputs 12, my intended output is 10. 
I'm running on a 64 bit linux machine.

Comment: `bool` is not a C type. How is it defined?

Comment: Yea it is pretty much, didn't come across it in my search, got the answer though, thanks

Comment: @leppie: `bool` was not a standard type in C89, but it was in C99 after you `#include <stdbool.h>` (and `_Bool` is a type in C99 at all times).

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your main program:

```
sizeof(bool) //should return 2 my guess
sizeof(char) //should return 1
sizeof(unsigned int) //should return 4
```

Every compiler can have different sizes for data types.

Answer (score 0):

Note That bool size on x64 is 2 bytes

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495970/why-is-the-size-of-this-struct-32) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983158/what-is-the-actual-size-of-a-struct-in-c).

Please check What packing? default packing (8)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of structure packing. Compiler would make the size of structure a multiple of 4 bytes. If you do not want this to happen and see size as 10 bytes in your case, use `__attribute__((packed))`

```
struct ID3v2_frame{
char id[4];
unsigned int size;
bool flags[2];
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Note that this might affect the performance of the program. See this SO question:

[Can __attribute__((packed)) affect the performance of a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454673/can-attribute-packed-affect-the-performance-of-a-program)

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be the terminator character in the flags and id array.

Comment: I seem to remember in my data structures class when you declare in array, the compiler always throws in a /n at the end to let the compiler know the string is done. So id would look like 
`id = [],[],[],[],/n` but i could be way off base too.